# How to get the network interface type

Tags: java, network-interface

Is there an option to identify the network interface type in java. The reason for asking this question is some set of Sun hardware boxes have a special kind of interface (DSCP interface) used for internal communication. We have an application developed for Solaris platform and I want to print only non-internal common interfaces.

To know more about DSCP
http://blogs.oracle.com/olympus/entry/dscp

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't much of an answer, but here's a tutorial that details [Programmatic Access to Network Parameters](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/index.html). That being said, it may also be useful to consult the [NetworkInterface API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html). Within the tutorial, there's a few working examples that will shed more light on the subject.

Comment: Indeed these special interfaces are of type point to point, we have an API to check the type. 


Thank you,