# find the network connection type(wired or wireless) by its IP address in java

Tags: java, inetaddress

I want to list all the devices connected to my network, I done like this

```
InetAddress i = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
byte[] ip1 = i.getAddress(); 
for (int b = 0; b <255;b++) { 
    ip1[3] = (byte)b;
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip1); 
    if (address.isReachable(3000)) {
        System.out.println("\tIP :"+address.getHostAddress());
    } else if (!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName())) { 
        System.out.println("\tIP :"+address.getHostAddress());
    } else {
    }
}
```

It prints all the connected devices but how to I identify which are wired connection and which are wireless, among them

Comment: I don't think this can be done. Whether a device is wired or wireless is part of the data link layer. It is transparent to the IP or network layer.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it in java?

Comment: Do you want to find out how the remote machine is connected to the network or what network connection of the local machine is used to reach the remote one?

Answer (score 0):

In pure Java, you are limited to what [`NetworkInterface`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) provides.

Additional information may be found e.g. in [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462498/how-to-determine-internet-network-interface-in-java).

Comment: Thank You, I want to list the different types of devices connected in my network with its details. Is there any possible,sorry, if it is vague one.

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112489/how-to-get-the-network-interface-type-in-java this is discussed as well. In pure Java this doesn't seem to be available. You could make a guess based on the MTU size, for instance. But this would be very vague.

Comment: We can not get other device's network interface from ours-Is it. please corect me

Comment: I am not sure I completly understand the question about other devices, but no, `NetworkInterce.getNetworkInterfaces()` will return your device's network interfaces only, for obvious reasons.

Comment: I heard that it is possible with SNMP,I don't know how. Any redirection will be really helpful.I want to list the  devices(system,router,switch) with its connection mode(wired or wireless)

Comment: I think I now get more to what you want, you don't want to know your local (i.e. your computer's) network devices, you want a network scanner. This is something completely different and I did not read that from your question and your tags, but now I understand the initial question better. Please open a new question regarding usage of SNMP (which will only be supported by certain managed devices, though).